# Geocoder .near() called from controller action throwing MySQL syntax error - Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps-api-3, rails-geocoder

I'm working on a Rails 5.2 project with a `Place` model, which is geocoded by the [Geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder).

Everything seems to work well so far, except when I run `Place.near("a valid location")` from the controller handling search, I get the below error:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*, 6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((-31.9575512 - places.latitude) * PI() / ' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(places.*, 6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((-31.9575512 - places.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(-31.9575512 * PI() / 180) * COS(places.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((115.9160093 - places.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) AS distance, MOD(CAST((ATAN2( ((places.longitude - 115.9160093) / 57.2957795), ((places.latitude - -31.9575512) / 57.2957795)) * 57.2957795) + 360 AS decimal), 360) AS bearing) FROM `places` WHERE (places.latitude BETWEEN -32.13741552118375 AND -31.777686878816255 AND places.longitude BETWEEN 115.7040152609056 AND 116.12800333909439 AND (6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((-31.9575512 - places.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(-31.9575512 * PI() / 180) * COS(places.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((115.9160093 - places.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) BETWEEN 0.0 AND 20)
```

This exact line works perfectly when executed from the Rails Console...

Any ideas on why the difference would be much appreciated.

**Place Model**

```rb
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode

  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude do |obj, results|
    if geo = results.first
      obj.place_id = geo.place_id
    end
  end
  after_validation :reverse_geocode

  def full_address
    "#{title}, #{street_address}, #{suburb} #{state} #{zip}, #{country}"
  end

  ...
end
```

**SearchController**

```rb
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
    # places = Place.all
    # places = places.where('title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:title]}%") if params[:title].present?
    # places = places.near(params[:location]) if params[:location].present?

    @places = Place.near("Perth, Western Australia")

    # @places = places
  end
end
```

### Update

Since posting this question, I've found that calling `.inspect` prints a complete ActiveRecord::Relation, **both** in the console and on the view (ie: with `.near` called form the controller), and calling `.count` produces the above error **both** in the console and on the view. I think this changes things quote a bit...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you call `count` or `any?` on `@places` in your view?

Comment: @spickermann yes, the error is thrown on the first use on `@places`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `near` scope build by the geocode gem and Rails' calculation on relations do not play well together.

Just force Rails to load the relation before calling additional methods like `any?` or `blank?` on it.

```
@places = Place.near("Perth, Western Australia").load
```

And use `@places.size` instead of `@places.count` in your view, because `size` doesn't fire an additional database query but returns the number of elements array when the relation is already loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! I've tried adding `.load` as you suggested, though it hasn't fixed or changed the error. I get the same response..

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot that `count` always fires additional queries even if the relation is already loaded (you might wanna read this [post](https://mensfeld.pl/2014/09/activerecord-count-vs-length-vs-size-and-what-will-happen-if-you-use-it-the-way-you-shouldnt/)). Please see my updated answer.